# How to namespace with twig.js

Tags: javascript, namespaces, twig

I can see with twig.js that you can use namespacing for template paths: 
https://github.com/justjohn/twig.js/wiki#user-content-namespaces

Where do you you specify the namespaces? Here it is in the documentation:

```
var template = Twig.twig({
    data: your-template,
    namespaces: { 'my-project': 'path/to/views/folder/' }
}).render();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That IS the specification...i.e. the next lines of the doc:

Ex:

```
{# your-template.twig #}
{% extends "my-project::template.twig" %}
```

The "my-project::" will now point to "path/to/views/folder/".

Comment: My question is where to set path/to/views/folder/ ?

Comment: That code you have does set that...thus I do not understand your challenge here - that code you have sets that value and this uses it.  Another way to say rephrase this is that the path you set contains the `templante.twig` file